# Check empty input and then run script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to run a script that check's if `#username-input` is
empty then run this script:

```
    document.getElementById('login-button').addEventListener('click', function ()
    {
        var name = document.getElementById('username-input').value;
        document.getElementById('username').innerHTML = 'Welcome ' + name;
        document.getElementById('username-input').remove();
        document.getElementById('password-input').remove();
        document.getElementById('login-button').remove();
    }, false);
```

**EDIT**

And if `#username-input` and `#password-input` is empty
an alert is popping up and say that instead of running the script

```
alert('username or password can't be blank')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use an if statement to check if the div is empty.

```
if($('#username-input').text() != '') {
    document.getElementById('login-button').addEventListener('click', function ()
        {
            var name = document.getElementById('username-input').value;
            document.getElementById('username').innerHTML = 'Welcome ' + name;
            document.getElementById('username-input').remove();
            document.getElementById('password-input').remove();
            document.getElementById('login-button').remove();
        }, false);
}
```

And for the username and password check.

```
if($('#username-input').text() != '' || $('#password-input').text() != '') {
    alert('username or password can't be blank')
}
```

Comment: check the edit, but that worked thanks, just need the thing in the edit if possible

Comment: Check my edit at the bottom. You just use the operator || to determine whether one OR the other is true. If you want to make sure both of them are not empty, switch || for && which checks if username and password is empty.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you aren't using JQuery so this would do it.

```
if (document.getElementById('username-input').value != "") {
    document.getElementById('login-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
        var name = document.getElementById('username-input').value;
        document.getElementById('username').innerHTML = 'Welcome ' + name;
        document.getElementById('username-input').remove();
        document.getElementById('password-input').remove();
        document.getElementById('login-button').remove();
    }, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //define the on success function.
    var onSuccess = function () {
        document.getElementById('login-button').addEventListener('click', function ()
        {
            var name = document.getElementById('username-input').value;
            document.getElementById('username').innerHTML = 'Welcome ' + name;
            document.getElementById('username-input').remove();
            document.getElementById('password-input').remove();
            document.getElementById('login-button').remove();
        }, false);
    }
    //Get the username and password.
    var userName = document.getElementById('username-input').value;
    var userName = document.getElementById('password-input').value;

   //validate the input
   //This if statement will check if either userName or password is null, 0, "", or undefined.
    if (userName && password) {
        onSuccess();
    }
    else {
        alert("username or password can't be blank");
    }
```